# How do I include another project's class libraries in my jar using Gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies

I am developing for Android, and I am trying to include another project's class files in my .jar file.

My build.gradle file for library project looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile project(':xyz')
}
```

My build.gradle file for xyz project looks like this:

apply plugin: 'java'

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The issue is that when I create another project that includes my jar library, it has unresolved references that exist in my xyz project.  When I **run** that project, it complains about not being able to find a class that exists in the xyz project.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on app , open module settings (F4), Dependencies, Green + and select library file. build.gradle is updated automatically :)

Comment: I see xyz library in there.  So, that is not it.  I have a library depending on a library.  app --> library.jar --> xyz.jar

Comment: @user306517 Are they both in there?

Comment: no.  library.jar does not contain xyz.jar - just references to it (which balk when they are attempted to be used).

Comment: @user306517 Both jars should be under dependencies. If your project needs both libraries to run, then both of them should be added. Since xyz is a jar, why is it compiled as a project? :compile project(':xyz')

Comment: I would like to hand out a single library to users of that library rather than have to tell them, okay, load this library and that library and that library, etc...